# How to keep track of software installations on linux while installing a software wt many dependencies?

Tags: package-management

While installing software for example nvidia-drivers or building software from sources, many times for 1 particular software out of the many others, a lot of debugging needs to be done.
In that debugging other unwritten dependencies need to be installed which are not present in the installation directions. Some of the installations are waste and do not solve the errors while others are a success.

If one wishes to automate this process using a bash script or a dockerfile, then one needs to know precisely what packages to install. This will include the correct installation of unmentioned packages as well.

How does one keep a track of the packages that were installed and did the correct debug as well as the ones that did not solve the problem?

Comment: The question is too broad. If you install software using apt, apt will take care of that. If you build some software from source, you really need to install some other software to be able to build it that may not be needed for something else.

Comment: Also it is in clear what you mean by "unwritten dependencies need to be installed which are not present in the installation directions", " a lot of debugging needs to be done", etc. Can you give an example?

Comment: Let's take tensorflow for example. I can uses pip to install tensorflow or i can build a whl file by compiling it from sources. Still any missing software can cause it to crash, let's take scipy for example, that too can be installed using pip. But if scipy version is outdated with the present tensrflow version and i have to install other packages to support scipy, those new packages become a part of my installation processes.

Comment: So when i am automating the installation process i am including scipy and the other dependencies i need to work with the current version of tensorflow. During this installation when i am trying to figure out which dependencies and supporting software to install to make scipy work, some other redundant software may get installed while debugging, but i do not want these redundant software to be a part of my automated software installation script. So how do i find which software are redundant? do i make a not of all installations and keep track manually or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: you can also take example of nvidia drivers. We can go to many blogs to figure out installations but still errors come while installing. While debugging one visits many forums and adds fixes and installs software/libraries all of whom may not be required to make the drivers work.

Comment: There is no need to go to "many blogs" to find wrong manuals about installation of Nvidia drivers. These drivers for Ubuntu should be installed from Ubuntu repositories without any errors. Installing software from sources is not a recommended way for Ubuntu and is obviously more complex.

Comment: The crux of my question is, while making automated software installation file, how should one know what dependencies are required for a seamless error free installation process, given i have installed the same software on my system

Comment: Deb files are "automated software installation files" and `apt` takes care of that. If you are using unconventional software unavailable as deb files, then you can pack it properly as a deb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer would be: install software using apt.

It it will install required dependencies and remove them by `autoremove` if they are not needed.

If you build software from source, you need to keep track of software you install manually with understanding what you install and why.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i think i have to keep manual track of installations for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For applications you compile yourself, you may use the `checkinstall` tool. That tool will, after compilation, generate a `.deb` package that then can be installed and removed using the APT system (i.e, using `apt install/remove` or other tools).

The tool is available in the package `checkinstall`. Typically, you replace the `make install` step by `checkinstall`. That will cause the creation of a `.deb` file that you can install using the package manager.

Comment: Well, it still needs build prereqs, that OP needs to track.